# How to resolve an AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, attributeerror

When I used the below code an  AttributeError occurred. Where the details are shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame as df 
import re


data = {'Tim': 'Tim@google.com', 'Rob': 'Rob@gmail.com', 'Jen': 'Jen@gmail.com', 'Wes': np.nan}

data = pd.Series(data)
    
pattern = r'([A-Z0-9._%+-]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]+)\.([A-Z]{2,4})'

matches = data.str.match(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

matches.str.get(1)
```

Below shown is the AttributeError that occurred.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-e12b5eab19b6> in <module>
      6 matches = data.str.match(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
      7 
----> 8 matches.str.get(1)




  AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I resolve the above error to get the below answer.

```
In : matches.str.get(1) 
Out: 
    Tim     google 
    Rob     gmail 
    Jen     gmail 
    Wes     NaN
```

Comment: `matches.get(1)`?

Comment: @ WF30,  Does below answers helps you to get your desired data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
matches = data.str.findall(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
matches.str.get(0).str.get(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal to get the desired result then, you can simply parse your data

### Your sample Data:

```
print(data)
Tim    Tim@google.com
Rob     Rob@gmail.com
Jen     Jen@gmail.com
Wes               NaN
```

We can simply use `str` method with `split` function as follows as we will get the desired names.

```
df.str.split('.').str[-2]
Tim    google
Rob     gmail
Jen     gmail
Wes       NaN
```

### OR

You can use @Allen's  solution by replacing `match()` with `findall()` as it fits the requirement as you have series data `data = pd.Series(data)`, please see difference below ..

**findall()**   Find all occurrences of pattern or regular expression in the Series/Index. Equivalent to applying re.findall() on all elements

**match()** Determine if each string matches a regular expression. Calls re.match() and returns a boolean

```
pattern = r'([A-Z0-9._%+-]+)@([A-Z0-9.-]+)\.([A-Z]{2,4})'
matches = data.str.findall(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
matches.str.get(0).str.get(1)
Tim    google
Rob     gmail
Jen     gmail
Wes       NaN
dtype: object
```

In order to resolve the error, `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!` you should use `astype(str).str` because the `data` has  float values `.` which it complains.

So, you can try below that works but not return what you want.

```
matches.astype(str).str.get(1)
Tim    r
Rob    r
Jen    r
Wes    a
```